# Loop the value of one column in a R dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

There's a data frame df, first 21 rows of it is:

```
       npi_one     npi_two weight hee_provn1
1  n1487676045 n1467400598    1     015171
2  n1952484560 n1467400598    1     015171
3  n1952484560 n1487676045    1     015171
4  n1467430777 n1508874751    1     015443
5  n1467430777 n1538176391    1     015443
6  n1538176391 n1508874751    1     015443
7  n1114030491 n1114977360    1     035084
8  n1114030491 n1912002742    1     035084
9  n1114977360 n1912002742    1     035084
10 n1508852716 n1114030491    1     035084
11 n1508852716 n1114977360    1     035084
12 n1508852716 n1912002742    1     035084
13 n1831185370 n1114030491    1     035084
14 n1831185370 n1114977360    1     035084
15 n1831185370 n1508852716    1     035084
16 n1831185370 n1912002742    1     035084
17 n1831185370 n1932248952    1     035084
18 n1932248952 n1114030491    1     035084
19 n1932248952 n1114977360    1     035084
20 n1932248952 n1508852716    1     035084
21 n1932248952 n1912002742    1     035084
```

I want to loop through this table according to column hee_proven1.

The code of first loop is:

```
library(igraph)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df2 <- filter(df, hee_provn1 == '015171')
df3 <- df2 [,c("npi_one","npi_two")]
l = c(apply(df3,1,c))
G <- graph(l,directed = FALSE )

d <- degree(G)
c <- closeness(G,weight = df2$weight)
b <- betweenness(G, weight = df2$weight)
e <- eigen_centrality(G,weight = df2$weight)$vector

cent_df = data.frame(d,c,b,e)
colnames(cent_df) <- c('degree', 'closeness','betweenness','eigen')
setDT(cent_df, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
setnames(cent_df,1,"npi")
cbind(hee_provn1 = '015171',cent_df)
```

And the result of the first loop (hee_provn1 = '015171') is

```
   hee_provn1         npi degree closeness betweenness eigen
1:     015171 n1487676045      2       0.5           0     1
2:     015171 n1467400598      2       0.5           0     1
3:     015171 n1952484560      2       0.5           0     1
```

And the result of the second loop (hee_provn1 = '015443') is

```
   hee_provn1         npi degree closeness betweenness eigen
1:     015443 n1467430777      2       0.5           0     1
2:     015443 n1508874751      2       0.5           0     1
3:     015443 n1538176391      2       0.5           0     1
```

And my final result want to put all the result table together

```
   hee_provn1         npi degree closeness betweenness eigen
1:     015171 n1487676045      2       0.5           0     1
2:     015171 n1467400598      2       0.5           0     1
3:     015171 n1952484560      2       0.5           0     1
4:     015443 n1467430777      2       0.5           0     1
5:     015443 n1508874751      2       0.5           0     1
6:     015443 n1538176391      2       0.5           0     1
```

For some reason I cannot use R package tidyverse, but I also hope it can be as efficient as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's an old question... but for the sake of the exercise, here's what I came up with:

```
library(tidyverse)

newdf <-
  df %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  mutate(rowid = as.factor(rowid)) %>%
  gather(key = "whichnpi", value = "npi", npi_one, npi_two) %>%
  arrange(hee_provn1, rowid) %>%
  group_by(hee_provn1, rowid) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(npi = map(.$data, ~ .$npi),
         G = map(.$data, ~ graph(.$npi)),
         degree = map(G, ~ degree(.x)) ,
         closeness = map(G, ~ closeness(.x, weight = .$weight)) ,
         betweenness = map(G, ~ betweenness(.x, weight = .$weight)) ,
         eigen = map(G, ~ eigen_centrality(.x, weight = .$weight)$vector) 
         ) %>%
  select(-data, -G, -rowid) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  arrange(hee_provn1)
```